# Determine if an integer is a member of a list of integers

Tags: vb.net

I need to determine if a particular integer does not exists in a datagridview column. I assume I should create an array of the integers from the dgv column, and then compare if the integer exists in the array. However, there is perhaps an easier or simpler way.

I have looked at many articles but none of them resolve my task. Some of the Stack Overflow articles show similar solutions but I can't quite determine what to do.

```
For a = 0 To Dgv1.RowCount - 1
    If Not Dgv1(1, a).Value = Dgv0(1, m).Value Then
         Dgv0(1, Dgv0.RowCount - 1).Value = Dgv0(1, m).Value
     End If
Next
```

I hope to compare an integer with a column of integers in a datagridview and if it is present do nothing but if is not present add it to the datagrid view

Comment: There's no really any point creating the array.  Just compare each cell value in the loop.  If you get to the end of the loop without finding a match, there are no matches.  Of course, a LINQ query would be the most concise way to do it.

Comment: Would you provide a sample code using LINQ ? I am very inexperienced using LINQ so I don't know what the code would look like.

Comment: I'm not sure about efficiency, but you could turn column into a list then check if list contains it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using wpf? If yes, create a model.
provide a checking mechanism at the setter, use observablecollection or list then bind it to the datagirdview

Comment: `DataGridView` is a WinForms control.

Answer (score 0):

Get the **row** and **column** of the **datagridview**

then **compare** (means condtional statement) to the **variable** you wanna check

and of course it should be inside of **loop**, loop count is equal to the count of rows you have in the datagridview.

Here's an example code:

```
Dim column As String = "YourColumnNameHere"
' Assuming 2 is the number you wanna compare
Dim value As Integer = 2

For row As integer = 0 to dataGridView.RowCount - 1

    If dataGridView.Rows(row).Cells(column).Value = value Then
        ' Do something here
    Else
        ' Do something here
    End If

Next
```

Comment: I don't think your solution will work because actions will be taken before the loop ends. No action should be taken until the loop is complete.

Comment: I think if the else 'do something' is a counter and the counter reaches the (rowcount -1)  then there is no match.

Comment: Then use do while loop since you don't want more than one result.

Comment: If the conditions were met then end loop.